# How to convert string date time format to another format using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

In my scenario, I am trying to convert date time string one format to another format `26 Nov, 2019 - 2:53 AM to` `yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss`. How to cover the format?

**Below Code Returning Empty**

```
let dateString = "26 Nov, 2019 - 2:53 AM"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")
let dateres = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
print(dateres)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
extension String {
func convertToDateFormate(current: String, convertTo: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = current
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self) else {
        return self
    }
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = convertTo
    return  dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
}
```

convert to required formate as

```
let dateString = "12-10-2019"
let convertedDate = dateString.convertToDateFormate(current: "dd-MM-YYYY", convertTo: "YYYY-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

**Step 1:-**  Put this function on your class file

```
func convertDate(date: String, dateFormat : String, convertFormat : String) -> String {
        let datetimeFormatOriginal = DateFormatter()
        datetimeFormatOriginal.dateFormat = dateFormat

        let convertedFormat = DateFormatter()
        convertedFormat.dateFormat = convertFormat

        if date == "" || date == "-" {
            return "-"
        }
        else {
            return convertedFormat.string(from: datetimeFormatOriginal.date(from: date)!)
        }
    }
```

**Step:- 2** Now using this function convert date

```
let convertedDate = convertDate(date: "26 Nov, 2019 - 2:53 AM", dateFormat: "dd MMM, yyyy - HH:mm aa", convertFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a")

print(convertedDate)
```

**OUTPUT**

"2019-11-26 12:53 AM"

Comment: Most Well-Come My Pleasure